# Python Comprehension With Range

Tags: python

```
>>> x = {'a':2, 'b':3}
>>> [key for key in x for i in range(x[key])]
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

Is there a better way to write this code without the for i in range(x[key]). Or is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3):

or use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

x = Counter({'a':2, 'b':3})
print (list(x.elements()))
# ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to do the work:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap, repeat

list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, x.items())))
```

This is how the [`Counter.elements()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) is implemented, which you could use directly:

```
from collections import Counter

list(Counter(x).elements())
```

If you want to stick to a list comprehension, then at least use the [`itertools.repeat()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) still, and use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) (or even `dict.iteritems()` in Python 2) to give you key and associated value pairs:

```
from itertools import repeat

[c for key, count in x.items() for c in repeat(key, count)]
```

All three produce the same output:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, starmap, repeat
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, x.items())))
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> list(Counter(x).elements())
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> [c for key, count in x.items() for c in repeat(key, count)]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

where the relative order of the keys is dependent on the [dictionary insertion and deletion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Comment: Wasn't me! But iirc, the Python 3 map can be used in this instance with arguments, I'll check for certain when I get home, a +1 in the meantime to adjust for whomever pointlessly downvoted this answer. I personally think answers which offer multiple ways of achieving a goal have more value than a de facto "do this" answer.